# iOS 5+ and dispatch_release

Tags: ios5, ios6, ios7, release, grand-central-dispatch

I'm developing an app that has its deployment target set to iOS 5.0. I've read several posts regarding the compiler complaining about using `dispatch_release` when the deployment target is set to iOS 6 or above, so it is not complaining for me, but I'm not sure if I need to handle this anyway. I've been testing on iOS 6 and 7 devices and I haven't seen anything weird... Could this be a problem, to not use `dispatch_release` or not depending on the system version running the app? Could it even be a reason for rejection when submitting the app to the Store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The availability of `dispatch_retain` & `dispatch_release` depends on whether you are building with ARC and on the deployment target used, but not on the OS release the code is running on (aside from needing to be larger or equal to the deployment target obviously):

If building Objective-C code with ARC and with a deployment target of iOS 6 or greater, `dispatch_retain` & `dispatch_release` are equivalent to the `-[retain]` & `-[release]` methods and are thus unavailable in the same way as those methods are unavailable and cause compiler errors under ARC.

If those conditions are not met (e.g. you are building pure C code, not building with ARC or use an iOS 5 deployment target), `dispatch_retain` & `dispatch_release` are available and can be used unchanged (and indeed **must** be used to avoid leaks) and the resulting code will run fine on iOS 6 or later.

See the headerdoc in `<os/object.h>` for more details, or watch the [WWDC2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) session on *Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC*.